# Scrollview not showing textfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I have a scrollview with frame (0, 64, 320, 44), i'm trying to add a subview "UITextfield" with frame size of (20, 7, 280, 30), I'm doing everything in storyboard. it looks good, i can see the textfield on top of scrollview However, when i run the project, in simulator, i don't see the textfield, i have to scroll up to see the textfield. i'm not doing any offset, i'm using xCode 5, but when i do the same thing on xCode 4.6, it works like a charm.

Does anyone know if it's an xcode issue or am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: What autolayout constraints do you have on the view, scrollview, and textfield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
[self setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:NO];
```